# Component isn't visible on the form

Tags: apache-flex, components

I made a very simple component to replace any component (e.g. a comboBox) on a form that is hidden if a user does not have access to change the value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
          visible="{!_controlToReplace.visible}"
          includeInLayout="{!_controlToReplace.includeInLayout}">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            [Bindable]
            private var _controlToReplace:UIComponent;

            public function set controlToReplace(value:UIComponent):void
            {
                _controlToReplace=value;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Label>
```

The same functionality of the component can be easily done by having a label on the form instead:

```
<mx:Label text="{objControl.text}"
visible="{!objControl.visible}"
includeInLayout="{!objControl.includeInLayout}"/>
```

With the component I can do this, which I like better:

```
<Components:ReadOnlyPlaceHolder controlToReplace="{objControl}"/>
```

But regardless of whether or not objControl is visible, it doesn't get displayed. Do you have any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: I'm confused. You're replacing a *label* with a *read-only* control? I understand this may be a simplification in order to protect your code, but it doesn't make sense. Also, what IS objControl?

Comment: @[Sam DeHaan]Sorry for the confusion. I meant that the functionality provided by the component is anyway easy to implement with a label, i.e., the component and a label are substitutes. The label and the component both replace another control (e.g. a comboBox) with themselves. I will clarify the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that binding is not updating the properties on the label.  Instead of using binding, just update them manually, ike this:

```
public function set controlToReplace(value:UIComponent):void
{
    _controlToReplace=value;
    visible = !_controlToReplace.visible;
    includeInLayout = !_controlToReplace.includeInLayout;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to show us your form and the layout code that positions and displays your ReadOnlyPlaceHolder.